# Access to the code of deployed angular 2 application using firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am trying to build a simple application in angular 2 using angular  material.

I tried to deploy my application using firebase console.And I am able to successfully deploy and update the deployment also.

But I have later updated my application and I am unable to revert back to deployed state.I need the deployed application to make the required changes into it.

can anybody please guide me through ,how can I get access to the files of my deployed project.And use them to make the required changes?